# How to change -webkit-scrollbar width when hover on it

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

I want to change the scrollbar width wider, so it looks clear when user hover on it.

So I wrote:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The background color changed to red, but not the width, Is there anyway to solve this?
Here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YPL8pmthXEcnXAUnPyeg?p=preview)

Comment: I think chrome blocks it, I tried here, and I just can increase the width with a hover in the div, or in another element with position absolute (but if the element is above the scroll you'll not be able to scroll by dragging)

Comment: But, -webkit-scrollbar is just for webkit browsers, in mozilla it will look different, I recommend you to use a jquery plugin, so you'll be able to stylize too

Comment: try this one http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html

Comment: @SpaceDogCS Thanks your advice, It's my personal project, so I just want to implement it under chrome.

Comment: did you solve it? @Allen

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava try `div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar` it only apply on div, It work when hover on div

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve that by using `border` instead of `width`:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ababab;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box; // <== make the border work
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    border: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This is amazing... but how can we add a transition to border - so that it is smooth

Comment: for me border: 0; didn't work, but any other value did. 
So I set ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb border to 4, and ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover border to 1, works pretty well.

Answer (score 13):

```
*:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

This will change the width and height of any element's scrollbar. If you want to be more specific, just exchange the '*' to a selector of your choice. For instance, to apply it to scrollbars of elements with the class of 'my-custom-scrollbar':

```
.my-custom-scrollbar:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It will change the container's width and height.

Comment: this works when mouse on the div with scrolled. What I am looking for is to not enlarge while mouse on the div, but on the scrollbar only.

Answer (score 4):

this is a workaround I used using mousemove event:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    let ele = document.getElementById('element');
    let distance = ele.offsetLeft + ele.offsetWidth - e.pageX;
    distance < 15 && distance > -15 ? ele.classList.add('more-width') : ele.classList.remove('more-width');
});
```

and styling would be

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}
#element.more-width::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
```

codepen sample: https://codepen.io/KhaleD_D/pen/OJpgJKM

Comment: Anything for horizontal scroll ?

Comment: Too heavy to bind mouse move event

Answer (score 1):

I use following code to achieve increase width on hover effect.
Sadly, its working on Chrome and Edge only. My apologies for incorrect formatting.

```
* { 
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border: 5px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: grey;
        background-clip: content-box;
       -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background-color: black;
        background-clip: border-box;
       -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this is SCSS syntax

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses scrollbar which is natively 16px large, but we show only 6px to make it thinner (and leave more space for content). But the trick is `overflow: overlay` which allows content to be displayed even over scrollbar area.

Using this approach you have thin scrollbar which enlarges on hover (and the hover are is a bit wider).

I got inspired by Khaled's solution, but I used CSS only approach:

```
.custom-scrollbar {
    scrollbar-color: var(--gray) var(--secondary);
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    overflow: overlay !important;
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: transparent;
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
    background: transparent;
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--gray) 6px, transparent 0%);
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--gray) 6px, transparent 0%);
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: var(--gray);
}
```

Comment: Note that CanIUse states that `overflow: overlay;` is being deprecated and replaced with `scrollbar-gutter`. See: https://caniuse.com/css-overflow-overlay