# How increase scrollbar width when user mover hover on it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I am using simple-scrollbar I need to increase with of scrollbar when the user mouse hover on it (same as skype scrollbar) could you please help me with it, anyone how to write a script in jquery.
(I just called css and js file into my HTML page)

below is my library for simple scrollbar:-

https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar#1-documentation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change -webkit-scrollbar width when hover on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505418/how-to-change-webkit-scrollbar-width-when-hover-on-it)

Comment: that's not working I'm using simplebar please ref link https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar

Answer (score 0):

try `#myElement:hover::-webkit-scrollbar { width: px; height: px; }`

Comment: it's not working I'm using simplebar please check out my link in my description

Comment: I want exactly like a  skype scrollbar when user mouse hover on it then increase the width of scrollbar

Comment: .simplebar-scrollbar:hover::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: px; height: px;
} maybe this?

Comment: This is also not working dear Radosik please refer this link https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar

Answer (score 0):

try this in .css:

```
.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical {
  width: 20px;
}

.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical .simplebar-scrollbar::before {
  left: 10px;
  transition: opacity 0s linear, left 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical.simplebar-hover .simplebar-scrollbar::before,
.simplebar-dragging .simplebar-track.simplebar-vertical .simplebar-scrollbar::before {
  left: 0px;
}
```